# Merging dictionaries in Django's views.py creates \n in JSON output

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Merging dictionaries in django's views.py creates \n in Rest API json output

> @api_view(['GET'])
> def json_test(request):
> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
> dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
>
> ```
> merged_dict = {**dict1, **dict2}
>
> result = json.dumps(merged_dict, indent=4)
> return Response(result)
> ```

> Result in postman
>
> " {\n "a":1,\n.   "b":2,\n "c":3,\n "d":4,\n}"

I am expecting \n to not show up in api results and should look like below

**{ "a":1,   "b":2,  "c":3 }" **

Comment: the `\n` is just put in as partof pretty formatting of the JSON stream, and is not part of the data, as you should know.

Comment: but that does not show up when not merging dictionaries, i even tried raw it shows \n as well, is there a way the REST API calls does not show that?

Comment: if it "does not show up" it is likely because the unmerged dictionary is so short itis encoded in a single line.

Just pass `indent=None` instead of `indent=4` in your `json.dumps` call to not hae newlines on your string.

But I think you are mistaking what the `\n` actually are: you __really__ should go to the Python itneractive console and play with some json encoding, and the print function.

Answer (score 4):

The `\n` character is part of the JSON string, not of the data conveyed in it, and is a needed character to represent a line break: you asked your JSON encoding with an indent of 4 spaces per level: if there is indentation, the JSON string MUST  contain newlines, so that the next lines are indented.

The reason you are not seeing the line breaks as line breaks is that postman choose to represent newlines as `\n` instead of actual new-lines: that is likely configurable. Otherwise, just add a `print` call to your Python code, and you will see the formatted JSON string in your console.

Just suppress the `indent` argument, or use explicitly the value `None` so that the JSON encoder delivers a "minified" string with no newlines at all.

In time: this hasabsolutely nothing to do with the fact the dicionary you are encoding being the resultof a merge, neither with the code being used in Django or Django rest framework. This just has to do with the formatting of your JSON string, hich you control by passing arguments to `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a `Response` is that the request determines how to render the response. So the client can ask to render it as JSON, but also as YAML, and with the right indentation. This thus means that you pass the data to the `Response` *without* formatting:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def json_test(request):
    dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
    merged_dict = {**dict1, **dict2}
    return Response(merged_dict)
```

in the `Accept` header in Postman, you can then specify the indentation with:

```
Accept: application/json; indent=4
```

in the *Headers* section. This is thus how the *client* can determine the output. The format is flexible such that a client can specify multiple acceptable formatting criteria, and the Django REST framework, which is the idea of putting a framework in between, will try to determine the best format to respond.

For more information, see the [*Renderers* section of the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#renderers).